# How to set the value of the discriminator key when creating a Model from the MongooseModel#discriminator function?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

With Mongoose I understand that I can use the discriminator feature to have different schemas living on the same collection using a discriminator key.

```
const options = { discriminatorKey: 'kind' };
const Event = mongoose.model('Event, new Schema({
 name: { type: String }
}, options);

const ClickEvent = Event.discriminator('ClickEvent', new Schema({
 url: { type: String }
}, options);

// on another file
const ClickEvent = mongoose.model('ClickEvent');
const clickEvent = new ClickEvent({
 name: 'sir',
 url: 'http://somewhere.com/hello'
});
console.log(clickEvent); // { name: 'sir', url: 'http://somewhere.com/hello', kind: 'ClickEvent' }
// look carefully kind is set to ClickEvent
```

What I would like is to have `kind` set to `click` somehow.
How could I do this ? I hope for something like this:

```
const ClickEvent = Event.discriminator('ClickEvent', new Schema({
     url: { type: String }
    }, { ...options, discriminatorValue: 'click' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mongoose 5.2+, you can pass the value as the 3rd parameter as specified in the [API Doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator)

```
const ClickEvent = Event.discriminator('ClickEvent', new Schema({
  url: { type: String }
}), "click")
```

and the `kind` would be set to "click"

Comment: Thanks yes that's available now in the new version of Mongoose